# How to skip customer attribute (created by third party extension) during Data MIgartion from Magento1 to Magento2?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, data-migration

I am currently working on data migration from `Magento1` to `Magento2`.

I found some customer attributes are created in `Magento1` by third party extension.

I am no longer using the above attributes in `Magento2`.

How to skip the customer attribute and its data during data migration ?

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the file **eav-attribute-groups.xml** under **the tab ignore**.

Add an attribute you need to skip into that tab, with **type = customer**

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<groups xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../groups.xsd">
    <group name="ignore">
        <attribute type="customer">xxxxx</attribute>
    </group>
</groups>
```

Please leave a comment if it works!

Comment: seems incomplete answer . Can you please explain what xxxxx means? It will be cool if you can answer it in generalize way. Thank you